# How to set ng-click on custom element directive in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this code I set ng-click to a custom element directive and I am convinced the alert "Worked from directive!" should pop up when a user clicks the rendered text. It doesn't work.

I know I can attached event listeners using JQuery-lite to the elem object but I am still curious why my code doesn't work and if it is possible to use ng-click this way.

https://jsbin.com/xobagigasi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body ng-app="myApp">

   <my-custom-element ng-click="runAlert()"></my-custom-element>


  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

function myCustomDirective() {

    return {

        template: '<h1>This text is from my custom directive.Click me and an alert should appear</h1>',

        scope: {},

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            //________________________________BEGIN 

            scope.runAlert = function() {
                 alert("Worked from directive!");
            };
            //_______________________________END 
        }
    }
}

myApp.directive("myCustomElement", myCustomDirective);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind click event to directive

```
  elem.bind('click',function(){
           alert("Worked from directive!");
   })
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.runAlert = function() {
            alert("Worked from directive!");
           }
});
function myCustomDirective() {

    return {

        template: '<h1>This text is from my custom directive.Click me and an alert should appear</h1>',
 
        scope: {
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
         elem.bind('click',function(){
               alert("Worked from directive!");
       })

        }
    }
}

myApp.directive("myCustomElement", myCustomDirective);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

 <div ng-app="myApp">
   <my-custom-element ></my-custom-element>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is function mentioned in `ng-click` **with the directive** should be present in the parent scope which is calling the directive.

Two ways to keep it within directive:

- If you want to access it from inside the directive, you can use `$parent` to access parent scope's function `scope.$parent.runAlert = function() {....}`

  [**JSBin Example**](https://jsbin.com/qocevafohu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)
- Use `element.bind` inside your `link` function to bind events to the directive element

Answer (score 0):

```
<my-custom-element></my-custom-element>

function myCustomDirective() {

    return {

        template: '<h1>This text is from my custom directive.
                <label ng-click="runAlert()">Click me </label> and an alert 
                should appear</h1>',
        scope: {},

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

           scope.runAlert = function(){
                 alert("Worked from directive!");
           }

        }
    }
}

myApp.directive("myCustomElement", myCustomDirective);
```